# Django 'model' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, object, django-models, django-views

I have a table which shows me the employees registered. I want to generate a simple HTML page according to their DB which includes their name, id, designation, etc.

To do so, I pass an id to the view so it can get the respective user's details and show me. Everything works fine until the error occurs **object is not iterable**. Here is my code below.

`report.html`

```html
{% if emp_item %}
 {% for some in emp_item %}
    <title> {{ some.employee_name }} Report</title>

    <h3>{{ some.employee_name }}</h3>

    <table style="width:30%" border="4">


        <td>{{some.id}}</td>
        <td>{{some.Annual_leave}} </td>
        <td>{{some.Sick_leave}} </td>
        <td>{{some.allowed}} </td>

        </table>

{% endfor %}

<h2>No User</h2>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

`views.py`

```py
@staff_member_required  # for admin login required
def report(request, id):
    emp_item = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'emp_item': emp_item}
    return render(request, 'projectfiles/report.html', context)
```

`urls.py`

```py
    url(r'^(?i)Rejectleaves/$', views.rejected_leave_show,
        name='Reject_show'),  # user leaves

    url(r'^(?i)report/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.report,
        name='Report'),  # user Report
```

`models.py`

```py
class Employee(models.Model):

    allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    employee_designation = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    employee_department = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    Annual_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    Sick_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
```

I want to see each individual user's data according to the process they have made.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change `Employee.objects.get(id=id)` to `Employee.objects.filter(id=id)`

"`filter()` will always give you a QuerySet" - it's iterable

`get()` - return single object and it's not iterable

Answer (score 4):

You are iterating over `emp_item` as an object list. But it is an object as `Employee.objects.get(id=id)` returns a single object rather than a queryset.

So what you need to do is remove the `for-loop` from the template as:

```
{% if emp_item %}
    <title> {{ emp_item.employee_name }} Report</title>

    <h3>{{ emp_item.employee_name }}</h3>
    ...and so on
{% else %}
<h2>No User</h2>
{% endif %}
```

But if you use `get` while querying, there is a higher chance that you can get an exception of `DoesNotExist`. So it is better if you can use `Employee.objects.filter(id=id)` to avoid any exceptions.

The `{% if emp_item %}` in your template is of no use if you are querying using `get`.

For better use, you can use `get` while querying and send a message to the template if exception occurs. For example:

```
def report(request, id):
    try:
        emp_item = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        return render(request, 'projectfiles/report.html', {'emp_item':emp_item})
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'projectfiles/report.html', {'error': 'No data found.'})
```

Then in template:

```
{% if error %}
    {{ error }}
{% else %}
    <title> {{ emp_item.employee_name }} Report</title>
    .... and so on to display other data
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable

Because I assigned the object made by [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) to `category__in` as shown below:

```py
                         # Here                     # Here
Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get(pk=1))
```

So, I assigned the queryset made by [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) to `category__in` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
                                                    # Here
Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

Or, I removed [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) from `category__in` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
                       # ↓ "__in" is removed
Product.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.get(pk=1))
```