# Django "TypeError: '...' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, django

I need multiple values to be in the courses' contacts, for example, phone, Facebook, etc.

---

I'm overriding create a method to make writable nested fields. Everything works fine with "branches". I'm confused because I can't get why Contact is not iterable.

**Models.py:**

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['latitude']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class Contact(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE, default=1)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['type']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.type, self.value)

class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    branches = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default=True)
    contacts = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Serializers.py:**

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    branches = BranchSerializer(many=True)
    contacts = ContactSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'category', 'logo', 'contacts', 'branches']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        branches_data = validated_data.pop('branches')
        contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
        course = Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for branches in branches_data:
            branch = Branch.objects.create(**branches)
            course.branches = branch
        for contacts in contacts_data:
            contact = Contact.objects.create(**contacts)
            course.contacts = contact
        return course
```

UPD: **Traceback:**

```
File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  114.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  20.         headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  559.         ret = super().data

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  261.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  526.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "/courseapp_task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  675.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 'model' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374741/django-model-object-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your nested serializers. The problem is in your models themselves.

A ForeignKey is a many to one relationship. The way you have defined things, a Course can only have one branch and one contact. Calling the fields "branches" and "contacts" doesn't change that, and neither does setting "many=True" in the serializers.

You need to change the models so that the ForeignKeys are on Branch and Contact themselves, pointing at Course. The serializer would then use the related names.

Note, you shouldn't need to define `create`; everything there should just work.